# Ubuntu 14.04 Install alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot

Okay, I was wondering what file Ubuntu sees in windows to know to do the option of install alongside windows? For some reason, when you update Windows 7 to Windows 10. Ubuntu still sees Windows 7 as the alongside install. But, when you do a clean install of 10. Ubuntu does not see Windows 10 at all. I want to do a clean install of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04, but would like to drop the file it sees on C: Drive after windows install before I install Ubuntu. So, what file do I need to pluck from Windows now and move to the clean install to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update grub so it will show windows 10 in its boot menu 
open up a terminal by pressing ctrl + alt + t

Type in

> sudo update-grub

I Haven't done a dual boot with Windows 10 yet but thats how its done with all other Operating systems i know about.

Comment: So, run Ubuntu off the flash drive or cd open terminal and run the grub update? Then it will see Windows 10 on the install? If you talking about updating the grub now? I have already done that with grub customizer. I want to do a clean install, because Windows 10 is giving me problems. Microsoft suggested I do a clean install, something about MBR needed to be 500mbs instead of 100mbs.

Comment: Are you saying its windows 10 it not coming up when your going though the install process.

Comment: Yes, I want to do my computer. But, I discovered this working on friends laptop. Ubuntu will not see Windows 10 and if choose the option (Do something else). It won't do the partitions on the unpartitioned space for the Ubuntu install. When I installed windows in the past. I would set the Windows partition in the Windows install and leave a unpartitioned space for Ubuntu. Ubuntu saw the space and Windows for the install.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, I want to trick Ubuntu into thinking its installing alongside Windows 7 and then I will do the grub update or just change it with grub customizer. I have read a lot of threads and there is really no fix for this yet, but if there is a way to trick Ubuntu. Then we might have something.

Comment: Flow thought this video  i know is says Manually Setup A Ubuntu-Windows 7 Dual Boot  but it will work with any version of Windows https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0W7XYAB4cLc Skip to 9 mints if you have done partitioning

Comment: Thank You, I never really knew how to setup partitions in Ubuntu. This is perfect, I will do this this weekend and let you know how it went. Thanks again.